# SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE doesn't work

Tags: android, view, softkeys

I have one `Activity` which has content view having its root view as **`FrameLayout`**, i want to hide bottom bar's soft keys for which i have added following code inside onCreate of myActivity but it doesn't effect anything.

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.myframe);
frameLayout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

Is there any permission or extra code which i need to add?

Thanks in advance :)

**Note** : I am trying this on Android **HoneyComb(API 13)**

Answer (score 4):

I guess all you need is to set targetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest to a proper one, say 11 or 13 for 3.0 or 3.2 repsectively.

Comment: Damn dude, that is on the spot... NEVER would have guessed that is the case!

Answer (score 2):

[SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE) was added in Api Level 14 (Ice Cream Sandwich). It won't work before that, such as on Honeycomb.

Comment: But on Honeycomb also you tube full screen does the same thing as SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE do, what is that then? is there any alternative for this in Honeycomb?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

Comment: i have already tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
Added in API level 14
and the one which is  before it was STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN and this is since api  11 but it's now deprecated

source http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN